# Why can't I build the iPhone app in xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, building

Hey, This maybe be a simple question but I'm not able to build my app in xcode. The Build and run button along with the breakpoints and Tasks buttons are not clickable. Why is this so?

Thanks

Comment: What about your target(s)? What do they look like? Do you have any? Could you please get more info and narrow down your question?

Comment: `The Build and run button along with the breakpoints and Tasks buttons are not clickable` means the app started running. Probably output window is hidden, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already built and ran the app, and the debugger is still attached.  Go to `Run | Stop`.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `Shift-Cmd-R` ( this should definitely bring up your output window if the app is running and by any means the output window is not turning up previously )